# mysqlnd statistics is empty though enabled in PHP 7.0

Tags: linux, mysql, php7

I use PHP Version 7.0.12-1~dotdeb+8.1 and mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev on Debian 8.
I am running several WordPress 4.6.1 sites .

I have enabled statistics for mysqlnd and according to php.info() it is actually enabled:

- Collecting statistics    Yes
- Collecting memory statistics     Yes

But the section "mysqlnd statistics" is always empty. Only zeros.
What could be the reason of a zero statistics for mysqlnd? 
How to turn it on?